# Pruning functions from LLVM IR

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I am trying to prune unnecessary functions from LLVM IR.

Let's say I have the functions `foo` and `bar` in my original LLVM IR. After optimization, all calls to `bar` were optimized away. But `bar` obviously still exists in the optimized LLVM IR.

Is there any to prune all functions that are never called anywhere in the modules except for a defined 'entry-point'?

Comment: The linker will do it, you do not strictly need to. (You can do better than the linker if you know the language-dependent rules about which classes and functions reimplement reach other.)

Comment: @arnt Thanks. Do you mean the llvm ir linker or lld? My issue is that I cannot lld-link my  object file because the `bar` function contains features not implemented for my target. Since the function is effetively optimized away this would not be a problem, except it still lingers in the object file:

```ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: __aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr0
>>> referenced by <string>
>>>               mymodule.cp38-win_amd64.o:(.ARM.exidx+0x8)
```

Comment: I can't recall using *any* linker that didn't, even the system-provided linker on [ultrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrix). Maybe your function is referenced e.g. by a vtable, even if it's not called. Pruning is easy, though, use `Module::getGlobalList()`,  `dyn_cast<Function>()` and `!hasNUsesOrMore(1)`.

Comment: @arnt Thanks for the hints. Now at least I know that I am probably doing something wrong...